# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, at stensakspapir.main(stensakspapir.java:34)

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I'm a semi-noob programmer and i want to make rock paper scissor, but it gives me this error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, atstensakspapir.main(stensakspapir.java:34)"
```

and from that i've resolved that i need to delete  "= null" after choice1 and 2 bet then it gives me this error

`The local variable choice1 may not have been initialized, The local variable choice2 may not have been initialized`

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class stensakspapir {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static void main(String[] args) {    

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String userChoice,
    choice1 = null,
    choice2 = null,
    compare,
    computerChoice2;


    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    userChoice=scanner1.nextLine(); 

    int computerChoice1 =
    (int)(Math.random()*100);
    if (computerChoice1 < 34) {
        computerChoice2 = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice1 <= 67) {
        computerChoice2 = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice2 = "scissors"; }

    compare = function(choice1, choice2);{
        System.out.println("The computer chose " + computerChoice2);
            if (choice1.equals(choice2)){
                System.out.println("The result is a tie!");
            }else if (choice1.equals("rock"));{
                if (choice2.equals("scissors"))
                    System.out.println("rock wins");
                        else{System.out.println("Paper wins");}
            }if (choice1.equals ("scissors")){
                if (choice2.equals("rock"))
                    System.out.println("scissors wins");
                        else{System.out.println("Paper wins");}
            }else if (choice1.equals ("paper")){
                if (choice2.equals("rock"))
                    System.out.println("Paper wins");
                        else{System.out.println("Scissors wins");}
            }else {
                System.out.println("paper wins");}
    };

    compare(userChoice, computerChoice1);
}


    private static void compare(String userChoice, int computerChoice1) {

    }

    private static String function(String choice1, String choice2) {

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is line 34? Something on that line contains a null-reference and that is wrong. You're not going to make this problem go away by surpressing warnings and removing proper initialization code - research what the exception is and fix the cause!

Comment: Those suppressed warnings will actually make it much harder for you to find the root of the problem since warnings usually are quite good at pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: You also want to check your definition of `compare` in the body of `main`. That is not a valid way of defining a function in Java. Move it into the class definition instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
          The null value is not compare  with other.like equals  

          Remove this 

          String userChoice,
          choice1 = null,
          choice2 = null,

          Replace this

          String userChoice,
          choice1 = "",
          choice2 = "";
```

[image]

The Program is worked

Comment: how to run the program in online, I've try to run in www.Ideone.com but, I can't run. it telling in error class.

Answer (score 0):

when program reaches if ( choice 1.equals ( choice2)), variable choice1 does not refer to an object. Its still null. To call a non static method, an object has to be created. coice1 must be given a reference to a String object. And by the way, the local variables must be initialized(unlike instance variables which are given a default value). otherwise the code won't compile.